# How can additional routes be added to anaconda kickstart?

Tags: kickstart, static-routes, anaconda

I frequently build centos7 servers and have a few special networking requirements.
For example, I may want to use nameservers or repositories in private ranges that can't be reached via my normal subnet or default gateway.

Imagine a kickstart with something like the following:

`network --device eth0 --bootproto static --ip 192.168.0.100 --netmask 255.255.0.0 --gateway 192.168.0.1 --nameserver 10.0.0.100`

`repo --name="private" --baseurl=http://172.16.0.100/private/7/x86_64`

It's a purely theoretical setup.
The theoretical box has an ip address in 192.168 range, with a default gateway that can reach the wider world, but would like to reach the 10/8 network and 172.16/12

Additionally, imagine that the default gateway cannot reach these other subnets.

On a live centos environment I could do the following

`ip route add 10.0.0.0/8 via 192.168.0.2`

`ip route add 172.16.0.0/12 via 192.168.0.3`

and to make persistent, this could be added to /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0

How do I get all this to come into play in anaconda? Historically this may have worked in %pre, but if I ssh into anaconda while it is running I can see that these routes are not in place.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just set up the static routes in `%post`?

```
%post
cat > /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0 <<EOF
10.0.0.0/8 via 192.168.0.2
172.16.0.0/12 via 192.168.0.3
EOF
```

If you need the static routes during installation, you can certainly add the appropriate `ip route` commands to `%pre` as well.

Comment: %post works fine and isn't a problem, however %pre will not work as you suggest (centos7 onwards). I thought the difference between network.service and NetworkManager.service could be rectified by adding entries in the format ADDRESS0=10.0.0.0\nNETMASK0=255.0.0.0\nGATEWAY0=192.168.0.2 but this also doesn't work.

Comment: I did have some luck though trying something from Fedora documentation: `nmcli connection modify eth0 +ipv4.routes 10.0.0.0/8 ipv4.gateway 192.168.0.2` as anaconda did now have a route for 10.0.0.0/8, but sadly it didn't have a gateway. I must be close now!

Comment: Check the kickstart log file for the `%pre` section, to see what might have happened.

Comment: Good suggestion. I added a dummy package "deliberate-breaker" to my kickstart so anaconda would halt. In another tmux window I read the pre-install log. There were no errors relating to the ip route commands but the nmcli command did produce some output `Error: Failed to modify connection 'eth0': ipv4.gateway: gateway cannot be set if there are no addresses configured`, this suggests I need to define eth0 via nmcli first to progress further.

Comment: Is the interface actually named eth0?

Comment: Yes. There would be different error along the lines of `Error: unknown connection 'madeup'`

Comment: What happened to a simple `ip route add`?

Comment: It doesn't seem to have any effect. I should try an ip route show immediately afterwards actually. I suspect a primitive networking environment exists at first courtesy of the kernel, then I imagine NetworkManager takes over. I think I'm going to have to make a bug/feature request to Redhat about this.

Comment: That's probably a good idea. If the docs are right, the network should already be up when `%pre` runs, but apparently that doesn't seem to be happening for you.

Comment: I eventually found the solution, see below. It still feels like more work than should be necessary. I think I'll let RedHat know.

Comment: Network is not up during %pre unless you use the kernel command line to get dracut to bring it up, and dracut has it's own (different!) network-scripts.

Answer (score 2):

I eventually found the solution

```
%pre
nmcli connection modify "System eth0" +ipv4.routes "10.0.0.0/8 192.168.0.2"
%end
```

This both works for the build, but also then stays persistent for afterwards

Comment: Thanks very much for this!  I'm trying to kickstart a server in which as much as possible comes off the net, and the package repo is (for some servers) not reachable via the default route.